# Is there any Android device with screen size greater than GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I've been searching through [glbenchmark.com](http://www.glbenchmark.com) for a device with screen size (width or height) greater than `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE`. I've found over a hundred devices with `GL_MAX_VIEWPORT_WIDTH` and `GL_MAX_VIEWPORT_HEIGHT` greater than `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE` (for example [Acer A110](http://www.glbenchmark.com/phonedetails.jsp?benchmark=glpro25&D=Acer+A110&testgroup=gl)), but no device with screen size greater than `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE`. So I assume there is no such device.

Is there any specification that guarantees that every device (or Android device) has screen size less or equal to `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE`? If not, is there any device that breaks my assumption?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can be sure that GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE will be always bigger or equal to the screen size (SurfaceFlinger requires this)

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for. For those who are interested: the requirement mentioned above is in the function [SurfaceFlinger::renderScreenToTextureLocked](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-2.3_r1/services/surfaceflinger/SurfaceFlinger.cpp), which appeared in Android 2.3.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with newest devices with screen sizes over 2k pixels wide you may find that, but hardware vendors would not put a mobile GPU that is not capable of doing offscreen rendering to a texture target because the max texture size is smaller than the device screen. For old devices with smaller GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, the screen were also smaller than 1024x1024.